# For indexing product attributes, more short text fields vs fewer fields with more words

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am planning to use elasticsearch to index product attributes. Each document should have around 60 fixed fields. I was reading the documentation about [tuning for search speed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-search-speed.html). It mentions that when **query_string** or **multi_match** query targets more fields, the performance is slower. Does that statement apply for **match** or **match_phrase** queries?

**Example**

Query 1:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "case_color": {
        "type": "text", // keyword type is not flexible enough in my case
      },
      "case_finish": {
        "type": "text",
      }
    }
  }
}

{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "case_color": {
              "query": "blue"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "case_finish": {
              "query": "polished"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Query 2:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "case": {
        "type": "text",
      },
    }
  }
}
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "case": {
              "query": "blue color"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "case": {
              "query": "polished finish"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is it better to put case color and finish attributes into one big field "case" than splitting them into different fields?

However, by putting all case related attributes into the "case" field, it would contain more words:

```
case: blue color, brushed and matte finish, plastic material
```

By splitting them into different fields, each field will have fewer words:

```
case_color: blue
case_finish: brushed and matte
material: plastic
```

I would like to know which approach is better.

Comment: That part mentioned in the docs only refers to **query_string** and **multi_match** (queries that can target multiple fields at once). This is my personal opinion, but if your fields are fixed (there's not constantly new fields popping up if new products enter), I strongly prefer option 1. If you ever want to provide aggregations, you can just aggregate over all `case_colors` for example, rather than having to do some filtering and parsing.

Comment: @StefanoBranco Thank you for your suggestion. Option 1 should be a good idea.  I probably won't use aggregations, but there will be a form that allows users to filter products on multiple attributes/fields using **match** or **match_phrase** in one request.

Comment: Option 1 all the way. Indeed performance is slower if you dont know where to search. In your case you have a context, you know you will find color in one field and other stuff in the second.

Comment: @LeBigCat, thanks. I will go the Option 1 route. I can see about 60 to 70 fixed fields per document. All of them contain less than 10 words. It should be easier to handle.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go even further than what's discussed above: ditch the free text and only use keywords (not in the mapping sense -- you can keep using `text`). What I mean is:

```
case_color: "blue"
case_finish: ["brushed", "matte"]    <---
material: "plastic"
```

Comment: Agree. And use terms instead of match query.